# Create dictionary with key from one dataframe column and values from another dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following df and wish to create a dictionary with `clust` as the key and `Feature` as a list of the values. How would I go about creating the `desired dict`?

`df`

```
   Feature  clust
0      I_0      2
1      I_1      3
2      I_2      1
3      I_3      1
4      I_4      2
5      N_0      3
6      N_1      3
```

`desired dict`

```
{1: ['I_2','I_3'],
 2: ['I_0','I_4'], 
 3: ['I_1','N_0','N_1']}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First aggregate list for `Series` and then convert it to `dictionary`:

```
desired dict = df.groupby('clust')['Feature'].agg(list).to_dict()
```